# Could not instrument class IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9

While learning and exploring Java 9 from eclipse. I create a simple project in eclipse, Although when I compile the project, it prints the program's expected result but along following exception too.

```
Could not instrument class mymodule/App: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.internal.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.internal.weaving.ClassfileTransformer.transform(ClassfileTransformer.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.internal.javaagent.Premain$1.transform(Premain.java:51)
    at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.loadMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

**Java code:**

```
package mymodule;

import java.util.List;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> immutables = List.of("Food", "Water", "House");
        System.out.println(immutables.get(0));
    }

}
```

**module-info.java file**

```
module mymodule { 

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems like Eclipse is yet to migrate to ***[ASM_6.0](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.ow2.asm%7Casm%7C6.0%7Cjar)*** which is completely Java 9 compatible.

On the other hand you're looking at the stacktrace which is similar to  ***[BUG#526383](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526383)*** and you can follow the same for updates.

Comment: Yes, seems that Eclipse to be using a version of ASM that doesn't support v53.0 class files. That said, it's not clear why Eclipse is running this code with an instrumentation agent. I wonder if the project has configured options that enable an old version of some agent.

Comment: I download eclipse Photon M3 package, then I download ASM from Marketplace but I got the same exception. Due to lack of experience I could not solve problem by my own therefore I end up downloading intelliJ idea for Java 9.

Comment: @UmairAhmed Well indeed that's another way to solve it, which I wouldn't have preferred to suggest though. Yet I hope Eclipse maintainers might want to have look at such indirect feedback somehow.

Comment: @UmairAhmed, Photon M3 is not a stable release, so a few problems should be expected. In fact Photon M3 is the only version that has this problem. So for now please use the released Oxygen.1a and/or wait for the next milestone build (M4 due Dec 15th), were this problem should be fixed.

Comment: @AlanBateman you are right, the agent shouldn't be used here in the first place, it is intended only for improving the debugging experience and has no business in non-debug launches, as is tracked in https://bugs.eclipse.org/526388