# I have errors with connection between Eclipse & MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I made this code with Eclipse. I can't understand why the following errors happen. Give me some advice please.

```
package test;
import java.sql.*;
public class ConnectionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sqldb?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
        String NAME = "root";
        String PASSWORD = "Ekarlekarl1!";
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, NAME, PASSWORD);
            System.out.println("connected");

        
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Fail");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

'

[image]

Comment: It would be good to see the errors :)

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using, and which version of Java? Your question could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47108914/could-not-instrument-class-illegalargumentexception

Comment: Eclipse is 2018-09  version, and Java is jdk 1.8 version

Comment: It doesn't really look like an error but rather noisy output caused by some plugin; the end result is "connected" after all, which would indicate a success.

Comment: @star2788 Your screenshot suggests you're using Java 11 (see the top line)